# Client Machine configuration from memory dump

Tags: memory, windbg, sos

How do I find the RAM size of a client machine using windbg from the memory dump of a process.

I tried vertarget, !address-summary. But i am not able to find the RAM details in any of these commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a `process` dump.  If you have a `kernel` dump you can use the `!vm` command.

```
lkd> !vm

*** Virtual Memory Usage ***
    Physical Memory:      262013 (   1048052 Kb)
    Page File: \??\C:\pagefile.sys
      Current:    458752 Kb  Free Space:    169368 Kb
      Minimum:    458752 Kb  Maximum:      4194304 Kb
    Page File: \??\C:\swapfile.sys
      Current:    262144 Kb  Free Space:    260460 Kb
      Minimum:    262144 Kb  Maximum:      1572076 Kb
```